# Android background service launched from activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, background-service

i was seeing this [turorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/) about how to launch service from activity
My question is: if user that uses my app close my app, service will continue to run or the close of app stop the service? i want to implement my notification service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) from the official docs for a detailed explanation on how long the service will run.

In most cases an app can't really close unless all its started services are closed.

Comment: so, if user close app from software management, service will not close until is work is not terminated? i want to implement something like push notification of iphone

Comment: you are thinking of an extreme case: force quit; when it happens the user is also prompted to close the process. Don't worry about this and implement the service normally, you can do push notifications.

Comment: I was thinking.. If user reboot phone? Service is closed stil user doesn't open app true?